# How to draw diagram in MS Word 2016?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2016

I want to draw a diagram for my office work. But , I cant find out the option.Kindly let me know the way to draw diagram on [MS Word 2016.](https://products.office.com/en-US/)

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your question is vague. Please [edit] it to include details of what you have attempted and what research you have done to resolve this. If you need help on [ask], check out the [help].

Comment: Also, it would help if you describe the nature of the diagram you're trying to create.  Word has some basic tools for diagrams, but if you need something fancy, it might make sense to create it in a program designed for that purpose, save it as an image, and then insert it.

Answer (score 0):

In MSWord 2016:

- from the top banner menu select the "Insert" tab and then select "Shapes" (it's about 5 positions over from the left).  You can then **Click** on the shape you want to add to your document (don't try to drag the shape onto your document, it wont work).

  - Your cursor will change to a "+" sign or other shape, place it in your document where you want to add the shape, and then use the mouse right click, to expand it in your document.

Hope this helps.